# Flash Builder 4.7 Icon-Small-50.png error

Tags: iphone, flash, flash-builder, itunes

I have completed an iPhone app using Flash Builder 4.7. However, when I attempt to upload the finished app, Apple's Application Uploader throws the following error:

"iPhone/iPod Touch: Icon-Small-50.png: icon dimensions (50 x 50) don't meet the size requirements.  The icon file must be 57x57 pixels, in .png format"

Anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Thank You.

J

Comment: Well, the obvious answer use an image that is 57 pixels wide and 57 pixels tall. I've never published an Iphone app, but that error message seems pretty straight forward. Is there some reason you think you should be able to use a 50x50 image?

Comment: Flash Builder creates the image sometime during the export process then puts everything into an .ipa file.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had an icon commented out... Ooops!